# Is it possible to convert a .spec file to a .feature file?

Tags: cucumber, jira, getgauge, jira-xray

I am using gauge framework for testing. I wish to store the execution results in Jira/Xray. But Jira/Xray only support cucumber for automated testing. I am thinking of converting the .spec file to .feature file and add it to the Xray test scenario. Then after executing the gauge test I am translating the gauge-json report to a cucumber-json myself. I am looking for a tool or a convinient way to translate the .spec file to .feature file.

Answer (score 0):

Gauge does not provide a way to convert specifications(.spec) into Gherkin (.feature). Gauge specifications follow Markdown format, there might be tools which can convert markdown to Gherkin. But Gauge will not be able to execute Gherkin syntax.

For the reporting bit writing a reporting plugin which can generate the report in a format which is accepted by Jira/Xray might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a spec=>Gherkin converter but in theory, you could convert the markdown to a Gherkin kind of layout just as means to have visibility of the steps in Xray.

If you aim to have visibility of the spec and detailed results, another option would be to convert the gauge report to Robot Framework XML kind of report that Xray can process. That would give visibility of each step result as seen in [this Robot tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Robot+Framework+integration+in+Python+or+Java), on the test run execution screen. Then you would need to submit this transformed report to the respective Robot REST API endpoint.